# Sometimes no Wifi on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, wireless, 20.04

I have a Lenovo ideapad gaming 3 machine with multiboot OSs (Win10 + Ubuntu 20.04).

Wifi usually works on Ubuntu, but sometimes there is no Wifi right after boot. It seems it does not load the wifi driver, because there is no option where I could choose/manage the Wifi connections. There is like 5-10% chance to having this behavior, so most of the time Wifi works, and restarting the machine immediately solves the problem.

Is there any idea how could I eliminate this behavior?

Here is my driver info:

```
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX201
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlp0s20f3
       version: 00
       serial: b0:7d:64:ec:34:e3
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.8.0-50-generic firmware=55.d9698065.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-55.u ip=192.168.8.151 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:16 memory:c7498000-c749bfff
```

Comment: Disable Fast Startup in Windows..

Comment: @ChanganAuto thanks, I did. I'll let you know if it helped, since the problem only occurred sometimes.

Comment: @ChanganAuto seems it worked, I haven't observe the problem since I disabled it. Thank you again!